# Draw a circle within circle at a distance of 10

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have recently started working with Android, And I need to draw a Circle within Circle just like below image at a distance of 10. If you see the below photo, I need to draw something like below circle with two diameters like that and I don't need any icons that are there currently on the photo. Just a Circle within Circle having two diameters.

[image]

I want to draw only the circles and two diameter, not the icons on the circle. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update:-**

I wrote the below code but it draws only one circle. I need to draw like the image above-

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(demoview);
        }

        private class DemoView extends View{
            public DemoView(Context context){
                super(context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                Paint p = new Paint();
                p.setColor(Color.RED);
                DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5,5}, (float)1.0);

                p.setPathEffect(dashPath);
                p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, p);

                invalidate();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: loop what you did, increasing the diameter each time.

Comment: What I did is that, I just created only one circle, and I was not able to replicate the above image as I wanted to do in Java using Canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5,5}, (float)1.0);

            p.setPathEffect(dashPath);
            p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);


            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {
                canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50+(i*10), p);
            }


            invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks AW101 for suggestion. After trying this, I am only getting the circles within circle, but How I can get two diameters also and have some sort of space left in middle, so that If I need to put the picture in middle then I can put it whenever it is required. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by a circle with two diameters?  Do you mean the horizontal and vertical lines? If so try canvas.drawLine. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html