# Android draw one arc within another arc

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, wear-os

I am trying to draw an `arc` within another `arc` at at distance of 10px in `Wear OS`.

We know that an `arc` can be drawn using the following:

```
canvas.drawArc(arcBounds, 0, 90, false, paint);
```

The above statement will draw an arc from 3pm to 6pm. 
I would like to draw another `arc` at the same `startAngle` and `sweepAngle` within the above `arc`.

Assuming that the total number of `arc` that need to be drawn is based on the size of a list, how can I achieve the expected output?

Here is what my original arcBounds init method looks like:

```
 private void initArcBounds(int width, int height, int additionalMargin) {
        float margin = res.getDimension(R.dimen.timearc_margin) + additionalMargin;

        arcBounds.left = margin;
        arcBounds.top = margin;
        arcBounds.right = width - margin;
        arcBounds.bottom = height - margin;
    }


for (Event el : eventList) {
      canvas.drawArc(arcBounds, start, sweepAngle, false, timeArcPaints);
      arcBounds.inset(10,10);

}
```

Comment: If you by "within" you mean toward the center, then `arcBounds.inset(10, 10)` will shrink the bounds by 10 pixels on all sides. You can easily loop for the size of the list, calling the same `inset()` and `drawArc()` each time.

Comment: Hmm basically I want something similar to the image in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549984/draw-a-circle-within-circle-at-a-distance-of-10, but in an arc form.

Comment: Here's 200px by 200px with your arc sweep, insetting 10px each step: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgXHh.png.

Comment: Right, so i tried the inset approach, but it seems like the inset is being applied to the outermost arc as well making it shrink as well, which is not what I want. I shall add a code snippet.

Comment: You can create a temp copy – `RectF temp = new RectF(arcBounds);` – and inset that.

Comment: So creating a new RectF copy for each element in the list?

Comment: No, just one, before the loop. Then `canvas.drawArc(temp, ...);`, `temp.inset(...);` in the loop.

Comment: Oh wow that did work. I would be more than happy to accept your answer if you can write up one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create concentric arcs inward, we just need to "shrink" the bounds by the desired measure on each side. The `RectF` class has the convenient `inset(dx, dy)` method which will do just that. It expects those measures in pixels, so we can simply pass `10` for each, with no adjustments needed.

This will modify the `RectF`'s bounds, so to keep those at their initial values in the original, we can create a temporary copy before the draw loop with `RectF`'s copy constructor.

For example, altogether:

```
RectF temp = new RectF(arcBounds);
for (...) {
    canvas.drawArc(temp, 0, 90, false, paint);
    temp.inset(10f, 10f);
}
```